# OpenGL cannot create uint uniform

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am wondering, why creating uint uniform fails? Is uint type removed in OpenGL 3.x (3.2 core) or just a bug in Nvidia drivers(337.88)?

```
#version 150
uniform uint picking; // glGetUniformLocation() = -1;

#version 150
uniform int picking; // glGetUniformLocation() = 3;
```

use in shader:

```
if(picking == 0) { finalColor = ....
```

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on. The type `uint` is supported in GLSL 1.50. And it wouldn't comile if otherwise.

Comment: Any tools to find out why is uint being cut out of shader?

Comment: There was a similar issue with the nvidia driver on OSX a while back, where `uniform uint` would crash the actual GL library - the shader (LLVM) compiler from the look of the stack trace. I don't know if it's a related issue. There was nothing for it but to wait for a fix.

Comment: I have a similar issue. glGetUniformLocation() returns a valid value, but the shader variable always has a value of 0 regardless of what I set it to. I wonder if it is because I am using glUniform1i() to set the value. There is no unsigned version thereof.